# multimap замена operator[] для доступа к элементу

Tags: c++, map

Судя по документации на **multimap** отсутствует доступ к элементам через *оператор[]* или *at*, в отличие от **map**. Есть ли какая замена для доступа к нужному элементу **multimap**?

Comment: Конечно, иначе зачем контейнер вообще? :) С помощью итераторов.

Comment: Следует использовать `find`. А оператор [] или at лучше вообще не использовать с мапами.

Comment: Вот допустим мне нужно получить myMap.second из [3] контейнера. Как правильно указать итератор?

Comment: Сам природа `multimap` уже понижает осмысленность такого оператора почти до нуля. О какой "замене" тогда может идти речь? Расскажите, какую проблему вы пытаетесь решить.

Answer (score 0):

Для `std::map` функция operator[] имеет совершенно не тот смысл, что функция operator[], например, для `std::vector`, `std::deque` или встроенный оператор [] для работы с массивами.
Для `std::map` operator[] это упрощение операции "обновления с возможным созданием". 
Для объявления `map<K, V> m`, операция `m[k] = v` проверяет присутствует ли ключ `k` в контейнере. Если ключ отсутствует, он добавляется вместе с ассоциированным значением `v`. Если такой ключ уже есть, то ассоциированное с ним значение заменяется на `v`.

Так как в `std::multimap` могут содержаться повторяющиеся ключи, то непонятно на какой объект, ассоциированный с ключом, operator[] должен вернуть ссылку.

Подумайте, точно ли вам нужен именно этот контейнер.